# Matching elements between lists in Python - keeping location

Tags: python, list, iterator, match

I have two lists, both fairly long. List A contains a list of integers, some of which are repeated in list B. I can find which elements appear in both by using:

```
idx = set(list_A).intersection(list_B)
```

This returns a set of all the elements appearing in both list A and list B.

However, I would like to find a way to find the matches between the two lists and also retain information about the elements' positions in both lists. Such a function might look like:

```
def match_lists(list_A,list_B):
.
.
.
return match_A,match_B
```

where match_A would contain the positions of elements in list_A that had a match somewhere in list_B and vice-versa for match_B.
I can see how to construct such lists using a for-loop, however this feels like it would be prohibitively slow for long lists.

Regarding duplicates: list_B has no duplicates in it, if there is a duplicate in list_A then return all the matched positions as a list, so match_A would be a list of lists.

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicates in `list_A` or `list_B`?

Answer (score 3):

That should do the job :)

```
def match_list(list_A, list_B):
    intersect = set(list_A).intersection(list_B)
    interPosA = [[i for i, x in enumerate(list_A) if x == dup] for dup in intersect]
    interPosB = [i for i, x in enumerate(list_B) if x in intersect]
    return interPosA, interPosB
```

(Thanks to machine yearning for duplicate edit)

Comment: I posted the same solution just a few seconds ago, but yours uses comprehensions and is faster :p

Comment: Your solution was working too and is maybe more understandable for someone who's not into list comprehensions :)
(But there is only A_indexes and no return ?)

Comment: To fit his requirement on duplicates you need something like `[[i for i, x in enumerate(list_A) if x == dup] for dup in intersect]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `dict`s or `defaultdict`s to store the unique values as keys that map to the indices they appear at, then combine the `dicts`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_offset_dict(it):
    ret = defaultdict(list)  # Or set, the values are unique indices either way
    for i, x in enumerate(it):
        ret[x].append(i)

dictA = make_offset_dict(A)
dictB = make_offset_dict(B)
for k in dictA.viewkeys() & dictB.viewkeys():  # Plain .keys() on Py3
    print(k, dictA[k], dictB[k])
```

This iterates `A` and `B` exactly once each so it works even if they're one-time use iterators, e.g. from a file-like object, and it works efficiently, storing no more data than needed and sticking to cheap hashing based operations instead of repeated iteration.

This isn't the solution to your specific problem, but it preserves all the information needed to solve your problem and then some (e.g. it's cheap to figure out where the matches are located for any given value in either `A` or `B`); you can trivially adapt it to your use case or more complicated ones.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def match_lists(list_A, list_B):
    idx = set(list_A).intersection(list_B)
    A_indexes = []
    for i, element in enumerate(list_A):
        if element in idx:
            A_indexes.append(i)
    B_indexes = []
    for i, element in enumerate(list_B):
        if element in idx:
            B_indexes.append(i)
    return A_indexes, B_indexes
```

Comment: You typoed (second `A_indexes` should be `B_indexes`).

Answer (score 0):

This only runs through each list once (requiring only one dict) and also works with duplicates in list_B

```
def match_lists(list_A,list_B):
    da=dict((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(list_A))
    for bi,e in enumerate(list_B):
        try:
            ai=da[e]        
            yield (e,ai,bi) # element e is in position ai in list_A and bi in list_B
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Assuming Python 2.7 or higher, you could just use a `dict` comprehension for the first line of the function; faster and more readable. That said, it's problematic, because it only maintains a single index for a given value, not all indices (it's why I had to use `defaultdict(list)` in my answer and avoid comprehensions).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def match_lists(list_A, list_B):
    match_A = {}
    match_B = {}
    for elem in list_A:
        if elem in list_B:
            match_A[elem] = list_A.index(elem)
            match_B[elem] = list_B.index(elem)

    return match_A, match_B
```

Comment: This solution would work, but it's really slow. For each element of the list A you browse the entire list B which gives O(n^2). Also `index` returns the first occurrence, so it fails if there are repetitions.